# Demonstrating Parseval's Theorem

Tags: python, numpy, fft

We were asked to show that Parseval's theorem holds for any input image. This is my working:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/content/tri.png')
img = img[:, :, 2] #red channel only
f = np.array(img)
f = f.flatten()
print(f.shape)

F = np.fft.fft(f) #fast-fourier transform

# space and frequency domain
space = np.sum(np.abs(f)**2)
freq= np.sum(np.abs(F)**2)/f.size
print(space)
print(freq)
```

The values do not seem to match as expected. What am I doing wrong? I am a novice to digital image processing. I tried it for some randomly generated 1-d array and the theorem holds valid i.e. both the printed values were same, but not image input. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

**Update:**
It worked correctly when I normalized the input in [0, 1]. But I don't know why the inputs had to be normalized.

Comment: on running this code getting ...   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That's because you cannot read the image. You could try with some image and replace the link in cv2.imread()

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the `dtype` of your numerical data to understand what is actually going on in here:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('sunflower.jpg') # since I don't have cv2 installed
img = np.array(img)[:, :, 2]
img.dtype  
>>> dtype('uint8') # my guess is that cv2.imread returns the same

f = np.array(img)
f = f.flatten()
f.dtype  
>>> dtype('uint8') # so is the numpy array

F = np.fft.fft(f) #fast-fourier transform

# space and frequency domain
space = np.sum(np.abs(f)**2)
space.dtype
>>> dtype('uint64')  # why does space gets cast to uint64 since f was uint8 ?
freq= np.sum(np.abs(F)**2)/f.size
freq.dtype
>>> dtype('float64') # why is freq float64 since f was uint8 ?
np.allclose(space,freq)
>>> False
```

Now let's run it again with the following change:

```
img = np.array(img)[:, :, 2].astype(np.float64)
```

which now verifies Parseval's theorem:

```
np.allclose(space,freq)
>>> True
```

In fact, in your **update**, by normalizing your input with something like `img = img/255`, `numpy` automatically promoted the `dtype` from `uint8` to `float64` prior to the rest of the computations, this is why it is working in that case.

To summarize, you just need to remind yourself that floating-point numbers are not the same thing as real numbers and they need to be treated more carefully.